# How did the paintings of the Middle Ages and the Renaissance survive to present day?

Tags: art

I mean, before the appearance of museums and galleries,how they kept them in proper conditions, coped with humidity and the right temperature?
If drying oils can last 2-4 hundreds of years with the help of varnishes, then the base (canvas, board) cannot.

Comment: Can you be more specific on which paintings you would like to know about? There are lots of paintings that are hundreds of years old and paintings have been kept in all sorts of conditions. For example a  Caravaggio was found in an attic that had been painted in the late 1500's early 1600's. Some times it's just luck that they weren't destroyed by fire, flood, war, looting, etc.

Comment: Re " the base (canvas, board) cannot", I don't think this is supported by evidence.  We have plenty of examples from archeology of wood and fabrics lasting much longer than a few centuries.

Comment: Idk, but would suspect that lower lighting and heating levels until early 20th century *might* have helped?